# Memory leak with ActiveX in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, activex, c++builder, codesys

I'm encountering a memory leak while using an activeX component in my project.
I'm working with Embarcadero Rad Studio 10.2 and developing a C++ industrial program that needs to communicate with a Codesys soft PLC on the same machine.

So, i have a ActiveX component that can handle the communication part between my program and the soft PLC.

I imported the ActiveX and everything seemed OK but i've found a memory leak that fills about 20MB per hour...
To import the library i followed the official guide:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Registering_a_COM_Object

I made lot of tests and I realized that the memory leak happens every time I work with ActiveX methods with variants involved. Looks like the program is not able to free some kind of temporary variants used by the component.

I've tested Visual Studio examples and everything works fine, so i think that the problems is generated by the type library that Rad Studio generates when I import the activeX component.
Also the ActiveX developer claims that everything works with Visual Studio.

I used also Dr. Memory and other tools that confirm the presence of the leak but can't provide details because i think the ActiveX is not compiled for debug.

Any idea about the reason for a behaviour like that?

There is some possibile incompatibility for an ActiveX in RAD studio?

Thanks in advance

---

**Edit**

An example that shows the ActiveX usage.

*Unit1.cpp*

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
#include <System.IOUtils.hpp>
#include "Unit1.h"

TForm1 *Form1;
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
    counter = 0;
    // Setting the path for communication setting files required for later connection
    if (TFile::Exists("PLCHandler.ini"))
    {
        iniPath = (wchar_t*)L"PLCHandler.ini";
        logPath = (wchar_t*)L"Log.txt";
    }
    iResult = PLCHandler->MCreate(&iHandle);

    try
    {
        // Creating the component and retrieving the handle for other methods
        iResult = PLCHandler->MCreate(&iHandle);
        if (iResult == 0)
        {
            iResult = PLCHandler->MConnect(iHandle, 0, iniPath, logPath);
            if (iResult == 0)
            {
                connected              = true;
                LabeledEdit1->Text     = "CONNECTED";
                long int numeroSimboli = 0;
                PLCHandler->MGetNumberOfSymbols(iHandle, &numeroSimboli);
                LabeledEdit2->Text = numeroSimboli;
                PLCHandler->MGetPlcStatus(iHandle, &iPLCStatus);
                LabeledEdit3->Text = iPLCStatus;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LabeledEdit2->Text = "ERROR: " + (String)iResult;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        LabeledEdit2->Text = "ERROR";
    }

}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Timers for testing purposes, they launch the next method every ms. Changing timing only delays the problem
    Timer1->Enabled = !Timer1->Enabled;
    Timer2->Enabled = !Timer2->Enabled;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Asking to the PLC Handler the value of a PLC variable, identified by name
    Variant varReceived;
    BSTR name = SysAllocString(L"Test.GVL.Test_INT");
    try
    {
        counter++;
        LabeledEdit1->Text = counter;
        // This is where i suppose the memory leak happens; the problem vanishes commenting the next line
        varReceived        = PLCHandler->MSyncReadVarFromPlc(iHandle, &iResult, name, 2);
        LabeledEdit3->Text = varReceived.GetElement(0);
        SysFreeString(name);
        VarClear(varReceived);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        VarClear(varReceived);
        SysFreeString(name);
    }

}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Timer1Timer(this);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Other test: destroy the component and recreates it: the memory usages remains the same, no deallocation happens
    try
    {
        PLCHandler->MDelete(&iHandle);
        iResult = PLCHandler->MCreate(&iHandle);
        if (iResult == 0)
        {
            iResult = PLCHandler->MConnect(iHandle, 0, iniPath, logPath);
            if (iResult == 0)
            {
                connected              = true;
                LabeledEdit1->Text     = "CONNECTED";
                long int numeroSimboli = 0;
                PLCHandler->MGetNumberOfSymbols(iHandle, &numeroSimboli);
                LabeledEdit2->Text = numeroSimboli;
                PLCHandler->MGetPlcStatus(iHandle, &iPLCStatus);
                LabeledEdit3->Text = iPLCStatus;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LabeledEdit2->Text = "ERROR: " + (String)iResult;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        LabeledEdit2->Text = "ERROR";
    }
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*Unit1.h*

```
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ExtCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.OleCtrls.hpp>
#include "PLCHANDLERXLib_OCX.h"

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published: // IDE-managed Components
    TTimer *      Timer1;
    TButton *     Button1;
    TLabeledEdit *LabeledEdit1;
    TTimer *      Timer2;
    TLabeledEdit *LabeledEdit2;
    TButton *     Button3;
    TPLCHandlerX *PLCHandler;
    TLabeledEdit *LabeledEdit3;

    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button2Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button3Click(TObject *Sender);

private:
     // User declarations
public:  // User declarations

    long int counter;
    wchar_t* iniPath;
    wchar_t* logPath;
    long int iPLCStatus;
    long int iHandle;
    long int readSize;
    long int writeSize;
    long int iResult;
    Byte     unbyte;
    bool     connected;

    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

And as requested the TLB generated by RAD Studio while importing the ActiveX

*.cpp File*

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// WARNING
// -------
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from a
// Type Library. If this type library is explicitly or indirectly (via
// another type library referring to this type library) re-imported, or the
// 'Refresh' command of the Type Library Editor activated while editing the
// Type Library, the contents of this file will be regenerated and all
// manual modifications will be lost.
// ************************************************************************ //

// $Rev: 87174 $
// File generated on 14/03/2018 11:22:13 from Type Library described below.

// ************************************************************************  //
// Type Lib: C:\PLCHandler_SDK_Windows_v16\bin\Windows\PLCHandlerX.ocx (1)
// LIBID: {BB4C0C2B-D94B-4F5C-A774-4DF59A2227FF}
// LCID: 0
// Helpfile: C:\PLCHandler_SDK_Windows_v16\bin\Windows\PLCHandlerX.hlp
// HelpString: PLCHandlerX ActiveX Control module
// DepndLst:
//   (1) v2.0 stdole, (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb)
// SYS_KIND: SYS_WIN32
// ************************************************************************ //

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "PLCHANDLERXLib_TLB.h"

#if !defined(__PRAGMA_PACKAGE_SMART_INIT)
#define      __PRAGMA_PACKAGE_SMART_INIT
#pragma package(smart_init)
#endif

namespace Plchandlerxlib_tlb
{


// *********************************************************************//
// GUIDS declared in the TypeLibrary
// *********************************************************************//
const GUID LIBID_PLCHANDLERXLib = {0xBB4C0C2B, 0xD94B, 0x4F5C,{ 0xA7, 0x74, 0x4D,0xF5, 0x9A, 0x22,0x27, 0xFF} };
const GUID DIID__DPLCHandlerX = {0xA51B6208, 0x4C76, 0x4E79,{ 0xAC, 0x93, 0xB4,0x15, 0x7D, 0x6D,0x97, 0xC5} };
const GUID DIID__DPLCHandlerXEvents = {0xF2CC045D, 0x93E1, 0x4FE1,{ 0xA1, 0x5F, 0xE6,0x48, 0x18, 0x85,0x35, 0x5A} };
const GUID CLSID_PLCHandlerX = {0x99036BDD, 0x9A94, 0x4ED2,{ 0x89, 0x61, 0x42,0x0C, 0x74, 0xDD,0x51, 0xCE} };

};
```

*.h File* is too long for the question body ([Full code here](https://pastebin.com/ebs16RMN)), but the MSyncReadVarsFromPlc method is

```
    VARIANT __fastcall MSyncReadVarsFromPlc(long lHandle, long* plResult, BSTR pszSymbols, VARIANT SizeList, long lNumOfVars)
    {
        _TDispID _dispid(/* MSyncReadVarsFromPlc */ DISPID(45));
        TAutoArgs<5> _args;
        _args[1] = lHandle /*[VT_I4:0]*/;
        _args[2] = plResult /*[VT_I4:1]*/;
        _args[3] = pszSymbols /*[VT_BSTR:0]*/;
        _args[4] = SizeList /*[VT_VARIANT:0]*/;
        _args[5] = lNumOfVars /*[VT_I4:0]*/;
        OleFunction(_dispid, _args);
        return _args.GetRetVariant();
    }
```

As you can see in the TLB, the MSyncReadVars method returns a VARIANT that actually contains an array of bytes with the requested variables values.

The Variant varReceived stores the returned VARIANT but is deallocated with VarClear when finished.

Any idea of what can generate the memory leak?

My feeling is that the returned VARIANT from MSyncReadVarsFromPlc is not deallocated after the method execution. But I can't see any way to solve this issue, also because same usage in a Visual Studio example works fine.

Can an ActiveX work fine in Visual Studio and not in RAD Studio?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing the imported TLB code and how you are using it in your project.  Perhaps you are not releasing the component correctly when you are done using it, or maybe it returns something as output that you are not releasing when you should be.  Really hard to say one way or the other without seeing what you are working with.

Comment: Yes, my question was a bit general because I was wondering if there could be some known issue for the described situation.
I'll edit the question for more detail. Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Yes, you have a memory leak when calling `MSyncReadVarFromPlc()`. It returns an OLE [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx), which you are assigning to an RTL [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant). That assignment **copies** the data, and then the leak occurs because you are not calling [`VariantClear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221165.aspx) on the original `VARIANT`.

Comment: I also see a number of other problems with your code. But the biggest one that stands out to me is that your Form's constructor is calling `PLCHandler->MCreate()` twice, which is potentially another memory leak, depending on what `MCreate()` is actually creating. And I don't see any code that is calling `PLCHandler->MDelete()` when the Form is closed/destroyed, only when `Button3` is clicked. The rest of the issues I see are not memory leaks, just opportunities for optimizations.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I'm really trying to use the information you gave me but I can't find a way to call VariantClear on the original VARIANT.
I'll keep try in this direction, I thought that the original VARIANT deallocation was up to the ActiveX...lot of unknown things to learn.
How can I point to the VARIANT instead of copying it? 

By the way, the double PLCHandler->MCreate() is a dumb error made while I was writing the example, in the real code is called just once. And the call PLCHandler->MDelete() only in Button3 is because Form1 is the mainForm so closing it terminates the Application.

Comment: Also, if I try to get the returned VARIANT address I received a compiler error:

`VARIANT *varReceived = &PLCHandler->MSyncReadVarFromPlc(iHandle, &iResult, name, 2);
 VariantClear(varReceived);`



The error:
_[bcc32c Error] Unit1.cpp(73): taking the address of a temporary object of type 'VARIANT' (aka 'tagVARIANT')_

Comment: @LucaMaccioni the function returns a temporary variable that goes out of scope when the function call is done. You cant take the address of a temporary, just like the error says. You have to save the temporary to another variable. But you don't need to declare that variable as a pointer. Use this instead: `VARIANT varReceived = PLCHandler->MSyncReadVarFromPlc(iHandle, &iResult, name, 2); /* use varReceived as needed... */ VariantClear(&varReceived);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you, I'll try what you suggested next monday...I can't do other tests before because my workplace is closed :D
Meanwhile, a further question: why saving the temporary variable to another VARIANT one is different from saving it directly in a RTL Variant as in my original code? I understand that with the code you suggested I mantain the value in a not temporary VARIANT that I can clear after the use, but I still miss how this can solve the original VARIANT memory leak.

Comment: @LucaMaccioni: A `VARIANT` is just a struct with data fields. Assigning a `VARIANT` directly to another `VARIANT` without using `VariantCopy()` just copies the field values as-is. Dynamically allocated data, like strings and arrays, are not re-allocated, the pointers are copied as-is. A `Variant`, on the other hand, is a class wrapper that has copy semantics. Assigning a `VARIANT` (or another `Variant`) to a `Variant` allocates a new copy of dynamic data, preserving the original. The original and copy need to be cleared separately, that is why you were leaking. You were clearing the copy only

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, sounds good. I'll follow you're suggestion and I'll give feedback asap.
Sorry for the bunch of comments but it's my first StackOverflow question and my netiquette is even worst than my code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Following your informations i finally understood and solved the memory leak problems, thank you **very** much! Everything works fine now.

Comment: @LucaMaccioni: I copied my comments into an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a memory leak when calling `MSyncReadVarFromPlc()`. It returns an OLE [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx), which you are assigning to an RTL [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant). That assignment copies the data, and then the leak occurs because you are not calling [`VariantClear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28741d81-8404-4f85-95d3-5c209ec13835(vs.85)) on the original [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx).

A [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx) is just a struct with data fields. Assigning a [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx) directly to another [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx) without using [`VariantCopy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ddbe1f-37b0-44f1-a3f0-b7ef4df88f8a(VS.85)) just copies the field values as-is. Dynamically allocated data, like strings and arrays, are not re-allocated, the pointers are copied as-is.

A [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant), on the other hand, is a class wrapper that has copy semantics. Assigning a [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx) (or another [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant)) to a [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant) allocates a new copy of dynamic data, preserving the original. The original and copy need to be cleared separately.  You are leaking because you are not clearing the original [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx), only the copied [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant).

Change your call to `MSyncReadVarFromPlc()` to save the return value to a [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373687.aspx) instead of a [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant), and then call [`VariantClear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28741d81-8404-4f85-95d3-5c209ec13835(vs.85)) when you are done using it:

```
VARIANT varReceived;
...
varReceived = PLCHandler->MSyncReadVarFromPlc(iHandle, &iResult, name, 2);
...
VariantClear(&varReceived);
```